# Encoding problem in aspx/html files

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a website in ASP.NET. I am facing a problem while I am trying to read the values from an `.aspx` page(using `jsonp`). I tried seeing this problem using Firebug and it was showing an error in one of my `html` files. Here's the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlQjC.jpg

I checked the respective `html` file and it was correct (according to me) except that I remember Visual Studio giving me some prompt regarding some encoding after which I saved the file. This was probably because this html file came from a Linux system. Here's my html file: http://pastebin.com/V3f6KDSa

Can there be such a problem because I then checked in Google Chrome too and it was giving an error as shown in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h67Me.jpg

I didn't see any error in this html file. I am guessing this encoding might be the error but there could some other problem too. I am trying to read the output of a `menu.aspx` using `getJSON`.
The output on my `menu.aspx` page is something like:

`foo({"1":"Jeff","2":"Mic","5":"Mark"});` in html form using this `.cs` code

```
outputText += Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(0));
            for (Int32 i = 1; i < k.Length; i++)
            {
                outputText += "," + Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(i));
            }
            //
            outputText += "}" +");";

            Response.Write(outputText);
```

Please suggest something to resolve this.

Comment: However, in Firebug a the end of my html file, these symbols are shown. Is this something related to encoding? http://i.imgur.com/NABRx.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `Response.Clear` before writing anything to the output stream:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Write(outputText);
```